# jQuery: How can I wrap <a> and </a> tags around existing images in a div?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm using [slidy.js](http://www.wbotelhos.com/slidy/) to cycle through several images inside a div.

My question is: How can I use jQuery to wrap `<a href="http://www.google.com">` and `</a>` around each image in the div (whose id is "imgFade")?

Thanks in advance!

Adam

Answer (score 8):

`$('#imgFade img').wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com" />');`

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use the [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Example:

```
$("#yourdiv img").wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com" />');
                      // Note: the self closing pattern ^ THIS is how you should define the wrapping element
```

This is wrap a link around all the images inside the div with `id="yourdiv"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's .wrap() method:

```
$('div#imgFade img').wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) seem to recommend including the closing tag, which all the other answers have self-closed. ie:

```
$("#imgFade img").wrap("<a href='http://www.google.com'></a>");
```